# How to I join 3 tables using Ruby Sequel?

Tags: sql, ruby, join, sequel

I have a database where Notebooks and Notes have a many_to_many relationship and Notes and Facts have a many_to_many relationship. How do I query the Facts associated with a given Notebook (indirectly associated via a Note) using Ruby Sequel. Should I create another many_to_many relationship between Notebooks and Facts instead? Would that be faster?

Comment: You could use has_many :facts, through: :notes in your notebook controller. the it would be notebook.facts to get the relationship object. Alternative is Notebooks.joins(:notes).joins(:facts).where(your query) which will return a collection of Notebooks.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557835/ruby-on-rails-how-to-join-two-tables][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557835/ruby-on-rails-how-to-join-two-tables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sequel ships with a many_through_many plugin that allows for querying between models through multiple join tables:

```
Notebook.plugin :many_through_many
Notebook.many_through_many :facts,
  :through=>[
      [:notebooks_notes, :notebook_id, :note_id],
      [:notes, :id, :id],
      [:facts_notes, :note_id, :fact_id]
    ]

n = Notebook.first
n.facts
```